# Concatenate 'date' and 'time in microseconds' in Dataframe to datetime format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I've got a textfile which keeps track of the date and time of the data collection. I've imported the textfile using pandas, and my Dataframe looks like this:

```
df
Out[10]: 
              Date                Time  ...      MP       ElapsedTime
0       2020/08/02        21:21:46 0ms  ...  230400    0.039999961853
1       2020/08/02    21:21:46 82191ms  ...      97   0.0490000247955
2       2020/08/02   21:21:46 164383ms  ...      21    0.058000087738
3       2020/08/02   21:21:46 246575ms  ...       0   0.0680000782013
4       2020/08/02   21:21:46 328767ms  ...       0   0.0780000686646
           ...                 ...  ...     ...               ...
330404  2020/08/03        03:00:33 0ms  ...    2037     4323.55500007
330405  2020/08/03    03:00:33 40513ms  ...    1964     4323.56400013
330406  2020/08/03    03:00:33 81026ms  ...    1975     4323.57400012
330407  2020/08/03   03:00:33 121539ms  ...    1949     4323.58599997
330408  2020/08/03   03:00:33 162052ms  ...    1877     4323.59700012

[330409 rows x 7 columns]
```

As you can see, the column 'Time' has a format 'H:M:S ms'. I want to use the 'Date' and 'Time' to construct 1 column which is in datetime format, but the 'ms' part makes it tricky. Right now, I've written some code to seperate H:M:S and ms, convert ms to fractional seconds and lastly concatenate date and time. But I was wondering if anyone has a more effective approach?

Thank you

Comment: Waht is expected output for `2020/08/03   03:00:33 162052ms` ?

Comment: since you accepted the solution for *milliseconds* - the title still says microseconds - which is misleading ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution if `ms` are miliseconds:

You can split `Time` column by whitespace to `df1`, then first column `0` convert to timedeltas, and for second remove `ms`, casting to intgers and also convert to timedeltas with unit='ms' by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html), date convert to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and sum all together:

```
df1 = df['Time'].str.split(expand=True)
df['datetime'] =  (pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) +
                   pd.to_timedelta(df1[0]) + 
                   pd.to_timedelta(df1[1].str.replace('ms','').astype(int), unit='ms'))
print (df)
              Date               Time      MP  ElapsedTime  \
0       2020/08/02       21:21:46 0ms  230400        0.040   
1       2020/08/02   21:21:46 82191ms      97        0.049   
2       2020/08/02  21:21:46 164383ms      21        0.058   
3       2020/08/02  21:21:46 246575ms       0        0.068   
4       2020/08/02  21:21:46 328767ms       0        0.078   
330404  2020/08/03       03:00:33 0ms    2037     4323.555   
330405  2020/08/03   03:00:33 40513ms    1964     4323.564   
330406  2020/08/03   03:00:33 81026ms    1975     4323.574   
330407  2020/08/03  03:00:33 121539ms    1949     4323.586   
330408  2020/08/03  03:00:33 162052ms    1877     4323.597   

                      datetime  
0      2020-08-02 21:21:46.000  
1      2020-08-02 21:23:08.191  
2      2020-08-02 21:24:30.383  
3      2020-08-02 21:25:52.575  
4      2020-08-02 21:27:14.767  
330404 2020-08-03 03:00:33.000  
330405 2020-08-03 03:01:13.513  
330406 2020-08-03 03:01:54.026  
330407 2020-08-03 03:02:34.539  
330408 2020-08-03 03:03:15.052
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `ms` actually means *µs (microseconds)*, you simply need to specify the `format`, e.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2020/08/02', '2020/08/02'],
                   'Time':['21:21:46 0ms', '21:21:46 82191ms']})

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']+df['Time'], format='%Y/%m/%d%H:%M:%S %fms')
# df['datetime']
# 0   2020-08-02 21:21:46.000000
# 1   2020-08-02 21:21:46.821910
# Name: datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

timestamps = (df['Date'] + df['Time']).apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y/%m/%d%H:%M:%S %fms'))
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.